# Roll20, Javascript document.querySelector not working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, queryselector

EDIT -- I provided a streamlined code below as well as an issue reported to the console.

Original content starts here -- I'm trying to get a simple chrome extension to inject into roll20's text area. I've tried a number of ways of selecting the elements in question. I know this is possible because Beyond20 does it. Regardless, all attempts have failed. The objects always return null. Even:

```
const foo = document.querySelector('#textchat-input');

alert(foo);
```

My most recent attempts:

index.html

```
<div id="test">
<button id="myButton">Press me</button>
</div>
<script src="libs/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

script.js

```
document.querySelector("button#myButton").addEventListener("click", postToChat);

function postToChat(){

  const message = "testing";
  const chatInputElement = document.querySelector('#textchat-input textarea');
  const chatButtonElement = document.querySelector('#textchat-input .btn');
  
   if (chatInputElement && chatButtonElement) {
    const activeText = chatInputElement.value;
    chatInputElement.value = message;
    chatButtonElement.click();
    if (activeText) setTimeout(() => chatInputElement.value = activeText, 10);
  }
  
}
```

EDIT---Let me try to simplify the code to hone in on what I'm struggling with.

```
document.querySelector("button#myButton").addEventListener("click", postToChat);

function postToChat(){

  const message = "testing";
  const chatInputElement = document.querySelector('#textchat-input textarea');
  const chatButtonElement = document.querySelector('#textchat-input .btn');
  
   if(chatInputElement==null){alert("chatinputnull");}
   if(chatButtonElement==null){alert("chatButtonElementnull");}
   
}
```

Both alerts fire.

Also this error:

> Content Security Policy blocks inline execution of scripts and stylesheets
> The Content Security Policy (CSP) prevents cross-site scripting attacks by blocking inline execution of scripts and style sheets.
> To solve this, move all inline scripts (e.g. onclick=[JS code]) and styles into external files.
> ⚠️ Allowing inline execution comes at the risk of script injection via injection of HTML script elements. If you absolutely must, you can allow inline script and styles by:
> adding unsafe-inline as a source to the CSP header
> adding the hash or nonce of the inline script to your CSP header.
> 1 directive
> Directive   Element Source Location Status
> script-src-elem     app.roll20.net/:6   blocked
> Learn more: Content Security Policy - Inline Code

EDIT 2 -- someone marked this as a duplicate while linking to multiple answers that don't solve the problem. The solution is an issue of scope. I will post a solution below.

manifest.json

```
{
    "name": "Charms Check Roll20 Extension",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "description": "A pre-alpha attempt to create a roll20 plugin for Charms Check",
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["https://app.roll20.net/editor/"],
            "js": ["script.js"],
            "run_at": "document_end"
        }
    ],
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "author": "MrLiioadin"
}
```

script.js

```
window.setTimeout(test, 5000); //ensures page is fully loaded before executing functions

function test (){
    postToChat("Charms Check Extension is ready");
}

const postToChat = (msg) => {
  const chatInputElement = document.querySelector('#textchat-input textarea'),
    chatButtonElement = document.querySelector('#textchat-input .btn');
    
  if (chatInputElement && chatButtonElement) {
    const activeText = chatInputElement.value;
    chatInputElement.value = msg;
    chatButtonElement.click();
    if (activeText) setTimeout(() => chatInputElement.value = activeText, 10);
  }
}
```

Delete index.html

Comment: `document.querySelector('#textchat-input');` is looking for a DOM element with the ID "textchat-input".  You don't have one of those, so it's returning null.  (Incidentally: you'll find it much much easier to debug things if you use `console.log` isntead of `alert`)

Comment: You're also trying to read input from what would need to be an `input` field (because you're using its `value`) but chatButtonElement is supposed to be a child element of it (based on the `#textchat-input .btn` selector). Inputs can't contain other elements.

Comment: Also you're reading `chatInputElement.value`, then trying to write the exact same value back to the exact same place, but inside a timeout for no reason.

Comment: And `chatButtonElement.click()` won't result in anything because there's no click event attached to that element.

Comment: Within roll20 the HTML is: 
<div id="textchat-input">
<div id="textchat-notifier" style="display: none;"></div>
<textarea contenteditable="true" role="textarea" style="width: 97%" title="Text Chat Input" class="ui-autocomplete-input" autocomplete="off"></textarea><span role="status" aria-live="polite" class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible"></span>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div style="float: left;">
<label>As:</label>
<select class="selectize" id="speakingas"><option value="player|-NDDnpFHiQAey9Z_sj_y">Adam F. (GM)</option></select>
</div>
<button class="btn">
Send
</button>
</div>

Comment: Also, the if statement never runs on the above code because the chatInputElement and chatButtonElement are both null. I should probably simplify the code to avoid distraction. Essentially, we're not even getting that far to find other problems.

Comment: I copied the HTML you included above into a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ht8sdonx/1/

In the fiddle, none of your queries are returning null against that html.

Comment: How are you running your JS queries? Are you just pasting them into the console and hitting 'enter'?

Comment: Everything works in JSFiddle. It doesn't work when it's run as a chrome extension on roll20. The chrome extension has three files: manifest.json, index.html, script.js. The latter two are posted in full above.

Answer (score 0):

I put together a fiddle with your example:

https://jsfiddle.net/96sungy7/

```js
document.querySelector("button#myButton").addEventListener("click", postToChat);
document.querySelector("#textchat-input .btn").addEventListener("click", exampleClickHandler);

function postToChat(){
    console.log('Executing postToChat!');

  const message = "testing";
  const chatInputElement = document.querySelector('#textchat-input textarea');
  const chatButtonElement = document.querySelector('#textchat-input .btn');

  if (chatInputElement && chatButtonElement) {
    const activeText = chatInputElement.value;
    console.log(`activeText: ${activeText}`);
    
    chatInputElement.value = message;
    chatButtonElement.click();
    if (activeText) setTimeout(() => chatInputElement.value = activeText, 500);
  }
 
}

function exampleClickHandler() {
    const textAreaValue = document.querySelector('#textchat-input textarea').value;
    console.log(`Executing the exampleClickHandler. Textarea has value: ${textAreaValue}`);
}
```

```css
#textchat-input {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="textchat-input">
  <textarea></textarea>
  <button class="btn">Example button</button>
</div>

<button id="myButton">Press me</button>
```

It seems like everything is working in your example, although I noticed that the time you passed to `setTimeout` is very short (only 10 milliseconds), such that `testing` flickers in and out so fast you might not see it. I bumped up the timeout to 500 milliseconds, so that it's a little more obvious that the text has changed.

Also, I added an `exampleClickHandler` so that you can see what's happening when you call `chatButtonElement.click()`.

Comment: Thanks! I'm also getting this to work in jsfiddle but not in roll20 and it's not entirely clear why. I do know that "const chatInputElement = document.querySelector('#textchat-input textarea');" returns null. It's like it's not quite able to read document. But, I'm fairly sure this is the same process Beyond20 uses.